# How to make pods stick around after helm test

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'd like tests pods to persist after running `helm test` so that I can inspect the logs.

But in Helm 3, running `helm test` runs the tests, prints the results (success/failure), and then deletes the pods.

How can I get Helm to keep the pods around after test execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a test Pod that included the `"helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded` annotation. Here it is in a lightly-modified version of the test created by `helm create`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "{{ include "test-helm-logs.fullname" . }}-test-connection"
  labels:
{{ include "test-helm-logs.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": test-success
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  containers:
    - name: wget
      image: busybox
      command: ['wget']
      args:  ['{{ include "test-helm-logs.fullname" . }}:{{ .Values.service.port }}']
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Removing the delete annotation allowed the pod to stick around for inspection.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding helm hook resources:

1. Any resources created by a Helm hook are un-managed Kubernetes objects.
2. In other words, uninstalling a Helm chart using "**helm uninstall**" will not remove the underlying resources created by hooks.
3. A separate deletion policy needs to be defined in the form of annotation if those resources need to be deleted i.e. “**helm.sh/hook-delete-policy**" annotation to be defined under metadata section in hook definition file.

Three different deletion policies are supported which will decide when to delete the resources:

1. before-hook-creation : Delete the previous test resource before a new hook is launched
2. hook-succeeded : Delete the test resource after the hook is successfully executed
3. hook-failed : Delete the test resource if the hook failed during execution

**Important Notes:**

1. If no hook deletion policy annotation is specified, the "**before-hook-creation**" behaviour is applied by default.
2. Any helm hook resources including test hook resource that must never be deleted should be annotated with "**helm.sh/resource-policy: keep**".

I hope this information is useful for someone.